# input number,It cannot be centered vertically

Tags: html, css

Center the numeric input box vertically in the content area
[image]

```css
input {
  vertical-align:middle 
}
```

```html
<p>
   <span>
     <input type="number" id="number"  value="8" min="1" max="20">
     密码位数
   </span>
</p>
```

```
To no avail
```

Comment: Try display: flex; justify-content:center; and align-items:center; on the p element

Comment: needed more clarification .

Comment: [your question is way too short to really help you...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `display:flex` to the span

```css
span {
display:flex;
}
```

```html
<p>
   <span>
     <input type="number" id="number"  value="8" min="1" max="20">
     密码位数
   </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the answer you're looking for? The numeric value will not be completely centered without a padding left and position relative because of the up and down increment arrows, just for your reference.

```css
input[type="number"] {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number"  value="8"  min="1" max="20">
     <span>密码位数</span>
```